# C# MSTest Test Isolation

Tags: c#

I am using MSTest to write integration tests which call a DLL. I need to load the DLL with different values based on the test, but the values in the DLL are persisting after a test is run.

Is there a way to isolate each test so that they each run in their own process or stack?

added code:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        LoadDLL(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, ReadDLL());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, ReadDLL());
    }
}
```

If Test1 runs first, Test2 passes even though LoadDLL() should have needed to be called. Conversely, if Test2 runs first, it will fail.

Ideally LoadDLL would go in a [TestInitialize()] block.

Comment: it is hard to help you in the absence of the actual code

Comment: Load dll into new appdomain and then unload appdomain at teardown

Comment: @Sentinel do you have example source for creating the appdomain? I am not understanding how to create it and the examples I found are old and not working.

Answer (score 1):

@usr1 It seems appdomain no longer exists in .nrt core, you have to use assembly load context. Try this and then try to remove the context http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/